No Ethernet interface on Ubuntu 20.04
This computer I access is not displaying any Ethernet interface anymore. On the network menu of the configurations window there is only the VPN GUI options.
Running sudo lshw -C network gives me the following output, which makes me think there is a driver correctly installed. Output is in Brazilian Portuguese, a direct translation is as follows:
*-network AVAILABLE
    description: Ethernet controller product: RTL8125 2.SGbE Controller
    manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical ID: O
    bus information: pci@0000:05:00.0
    version: 05
    width: 64-bit
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm mst pctexpress mstx vpd bus_master cap_ltst
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: I/O port: 3000(size=256) memory:53200000-532effff memOri a:53210080-5321 fff

I tried installing the driver using the latest .deb in https://github.com/awesometic/realtek-r8125-dkms, but nothing changed. I'm not that familiar with linux, so I have no clue where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.
A few additional information:

The network connection did work before, this computer was mainly accessed via SSH. After purging and re-installing the NVIDIA driver and restarting the computer a no-route problem was identified when trying to access it via SSH. Checking the computer in the location showed the mentioned problem.
There is no VPN active, what I meant was in the GUI menu of the network configurations, there is only options for VPN, nothing about Ethernet.
I thought something got corrupted with a driver, which caused the OS to no longer recognize the Ethernet interface, and maybe installing the driver could fix it.
I don't think there has been a kernel upgrade. But I can't be sure, I'm not very familiar with Linux.

I ran lspci -nnk thinking it might be helpful in diagnosing the problem. Here is the output:
$ lspci -nnk 
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8700] (rev 01)  
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co.. Ltd Device [1458:5000] 
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a70d] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a74d] (rev 01)   
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a60] (rev 11) 
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5007]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd Kernel nodules: xhci_pci 
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a27] (rev 11) 
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a4c] (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a4d] (rev 11)
    DeviceNane: Onboard - Other 
00:15.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8886:7a4e] (rev 11) DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
00:15.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8886:7a4f] (rev 11) DeviceNane: Onboard - Other 
00:16.0 Communication controller [8788]: Intel Corporation Device [8886:7a68] (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:1c3a] 
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a62] (rev 11) 
    DeviceNane: Onboard - SATA 
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:b005] 
    Kernel driver in use: ahci Kernel modules: ahci 
00:19.8 Serial bus controller [9c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a7c] (rev 11) 
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
00:19.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a7d] (rev 11) 
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
00:1a.0 PCI bridge [0684]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a48] (rev 11) 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a38] (rev 11) 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [8684]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a3a] (rev 11) 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport 
00:lf.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a06] (rev 11) 
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5001] 
00:1f.3 Audio device [0483]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7.50] (rev 11) 
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound 
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:a194] 
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a23] (rev 11) 
    DeviceNane: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:5001] 08:11.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7a24] (rev 11) 
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [8308]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2504] (rev al) 
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2504] 
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb 
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:228e] (rev al) 
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2504] 
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0188]: Micron/Crucial Technology Device [c0a9:540.5] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Micron/Crucial Technology Device [c0a9:5021] 
    Kernel driver in use: nvme Kernel modules: none 
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]. Micron/Crucial Technology Device [c0a9:540a] (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Micron/Crucial Technology Device [c0a9:5021]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme 
    Kernel modules: nvme 
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05) 
    Subsystem: Gigab to Technol.. Co., Ltd RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller 1458:e000 


Did it work and has stopped working? Does it work if you turn off the VPN? If it worked and now does not why do you think you need to install the driver? Has there been a recent kernel upgrade and now it has stopped working? Please try and answer all of these with an edit to the question not as a comment.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].

The post has been edited to include your questions, hope it helps clearing it.
